# How to disable Apache Http Cleint 4.3 url encoding

Tags: apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've tried to look in documentation and in the source and I can't find a way to disable;e the built in url encoding. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: sounds like a **really bad idea ™**

Comment: The server I am using already encodes as well. That's bad but a given. Currently the url is encoded twice. not good.
I need a way to disable the client side encoding.

Comment: Oh that makes sense then. sounds like oleg answered it for you below. if his answer fixed the problem, i highly suggest you select it as the accepted answer. good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BasicHttpRequest` instead of `HttpGet`. Request URI in BasicHttpRequest can contain arbitrary garbage that HttpClient will make no attempts to convert to a valid URI

Comment: I fail to see the difference between the 2 classes. Both don't look to handle encoding.

Comment: That's because request URI rewriting is done by protocol handlers, not by POJOs that represent an HTTP message